# A model of set theory (ZFC) that contain a model of ZFC.

Tags: set-theory

If we suppose $ZFC + \exists \text { transitive standard model} (M,\in)  \text{of }  ZFC$  and then we find a model $(N,\in_{N})$ of ZFC that is a proper end elementary extension of M and contain a set $(N',\in_{N'}=\in_{N}\cap(N'\times N'))\in N$ such that $(N',\in_{N'})\approx(M,\in)$, then is a model of $ZFC^{N'}$ , we obtain contradiction with the second Godel theorem?

Comment: Why is this going to be a contradiction?

Comment: @Asaf Karagila.I  edited the question.

Comment: No, we do not. Obviously.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $ZFC^{N'} $? I strongly suspect you have not yet stated correctly the question you have in mind.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo. I mean the formulas of ZFC as they are seen in N', as a subset of the hereditary finite sets of N', that  because $N'\approx M$ ,they are the same than in M.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo. I mean  M,N,N' are $\omega $-models.

Comment: If you are only looking at $\omega $-models, then $ZFC^{N'}$ is just ZFC. Anyway, if this were not the case, it would not make sense to ask for a model of $ZFC^{N'} $, unless the question is to take place inside $N'$ or a related model, but this then needs to be made explicit in the body of the question.

Comment: In any case, you may even have standard ordinals $\alpha <\beta $ such that $(L_\alpha,\in)\prec (L_\beta,\in)\models\mathsf {ZFC} $. I imagine the question you are really after is whether you can prove in $\mathsf{ZFC}+$"there is a transitive model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$" that there is some transitive model $M $ such that there is such an $N $ as indicated. Is this closer to what you are after?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59111/discussion-between-luis-and-andres-e-caicedo).

Comment: No, let's not.${}$

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo. yes, it is related with it. If it is possible from any M transitive standard to find N,
such that N is a elementary end extension and $M\in N$ ?
And Is it possible to prove $\alpha <\beta $ such that $(L_\alpha,\in)\prec (L_\beta,\in)\models\mathsf {ZFC} $ from $\mathsf{ZFC}+$"there is a transitive model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$" ?, and how to prove?

Comment: You should probably edit the question making the new version explicit.

Answer (score 0):

We have to be careful here about *what theory* is proving *what statement* about *what kinds of models*.

So let's start small. ZFC does **not** prove the statement "there is a model of ZFC" (let alone "there is a transitive model of ZFC" or etc.). This does **not** prevent *some models* of ZFC from satisfying "there is a model of ZFC": ZFC proves $\varphi$ iff $\varphi$ is true in *every* model of ZFC, so all that we know is that *some* models of ZFC satisfy "there is a model of ZFC."

Now suppose $M$ is a model of ZFC+"There is a transitive model of ZFC" - that is, there is some $N\in M$ such that $M$ thinks "$N$ is a transitive model of ZFC." Then we **do not know** whether, in $M$, $N$ is contained in some larger transitive model (that is, whether there is an $N'\in M$ with $N\subseteq N'$ and $N'$ is a transitive model of ZFC, in the sense of $M$). This is because such an $N'$ satisfies ZFC+"There is a transitive model of ZFC," so if this were always true then the completeness theorem would tell us ZFC+"There is a transitive model of ZFC" proves Con(ZFC+"There is a transitive model of ZFC"), contradicting Godel (that is, assuming ZFC+"There is a transitive model of ZFC" is in fact consistent).

Now if we think about the paragraph above, we'll quickly see that the word "transitive" isn't really relevant. By the same argument, there is (assuming ZFC+Con(ZFC) is consistent) a model $M$ of ZFC+Con(ZFC) containing a model $N$ of ZFC, such that $M$ **does not** contain any $N'$ containing $N$ and satisfying ZFC. And again, this doesn't prevent *other* models of ZFC from exhibiting the opposite behavior, e.g. the extreme property "every set is contained in a transitive model of ZFC."

---

So the answer to your question as posed - "... we obtain contradiction with the second Godel theorem?" is **no**: the *existence* of a model of a theory with certain properties doesn't imply that *every* model of that theory has certain properties, so being able to *in some instances* build such an extension doesn't contradict Godel at all, even though *those models* will satisfy strong consistency properties; conversely, given any procedure you can think of for extending models of ZFC, there will be models of ZFC+Con(ZFC) where that procedure doesn't work. The procedure you have in mind will probably work *under further assumptions*, which of course means that we do not have a contradiction with Godel after all.